# Why isn't the taproot deployment buried in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, taproot, soft-fork, activation, bip90-buried-deployments

Bitcoin Inquisition recently had a [PR about soft fork activation](https://bitcoincore.reviews/bitcoin-inquisition-16) and as part that PR, it buries taproot and references [a closed PR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/23505) to Bitcoin Core to bury taproot. Will the taproot deployment be buried in Bitcoin Core and if so, what needs to be in place to bury it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Taproot deployment is buried insofar as consensus no longer checks its status to determine whether to enforce the Taproot rules. The Taproot rules are enforced from genesis now, with the (hardcoded) exception of a single block.

Burying is generally for a performance improvement resulting from not needing to constantly check the deployment status. Since Taproot rules are always used, there's no need to specify a buried deployment height nor to remove the deployment parameters, and so the deployment parameters remain. The deployment code is only called when users use `getdeploymentinfo`, and in that case, it may be useful to have the historic deployment information rather than stating that it is buried.

Comment: Is that hardcoded exception a block that would violate Taproot rules?

Comment: Yes. There is a single block mined prior to Taproot activation that violates the Taproot rules. All other blocks in the blockchain pass with the Taproot rules.

Comment: What block and what does it violate exactly? Thanks

Comment: @PaulOtto Block 692261 contains a taproot-invalid spend.